# Reset LinearPercentIndicator after timer expire in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator package for my timer.

My LinearPercentIndicator configuration

`LinearPercentIndicator(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, right: 2.0),
            lineHeight: 4.0,
            percent: this.percent,
            animationDuration: timerInMiliSec,
            animation: true,
            progressColor: progressColor,
            addAutomaticKeepAlive: false,
          ),`

[image]

The requirement is very simple. once time expires LinearPercentIndicator has to start for begging. But it's working only first time once its get filled it stop at that point.

any hint clue will be helpful.

Regard 
Prashant

Comment: have you use percent dynamic with apply stateState ? means when progress complete add percentage 0.

Comment: Hi amit yes tried the same. If I make percent 0 on setState it gets stuck on second time.

Comment: Sorry try with 0.1 and increment that percent with your timer